# HTML5 Storage between browsers (on an iphone)?

Tags: iphone, html, local-storage

Is there any way to have localstorage persist across browsers? I have a system that uses localstorage to track which iphone is accessing my system (it's a controlled environment), but I would like it to work regardless of the browser - if they register their phone using Safari, I want to know the registration key that gets stored (currently using localstorage) even if they use a different browser.

Is this possible? Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

No, localStorage is local storage for the current domain and only accessible on the particular browser implementation.  It will not and can not ever be used across browsers or devices or different domains.

You need to store the key on a server somewhere, so that the different browsers can both access it.  Or perhaps there is some native feature for iOS that both browsers can access, but i wouldn't know about that kind of thing.

Comment: The key is stored on the server. I need to identify which hardware is accessing the system ideally without needing an app (simply because of cost). HTML5 localstorage is the best I've been able to find so far.

Comment: Unfortunately, the localStorage objects provided by Safari or Chrome or Opera or whatever are completely separate with no way to access them from other browsers, by design, just like cookies are specific to a browser.